# Search through *.gz files with keeping the file name

Tags: grep, gzip, zcat

Say I have multiple `.gz` files that I want to search a keyword in them. I can do this by piping `zcat` result to a `grep` like this:

```
zcat some.file.* | grep "keyword_1" | ... | grep "keyword_n"
```

The output of this command though will be just the matching line and won't have the file name in it. Is there any way I can attach the file name to the `zcat` output?

Comment: Instead of `zcat`, what about `zgrep` with `-H` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `zgrep` instead of `zcat`:

```
zgrep -H keyword some.file.*
```

And if you want to use `egrep` to get pattern matching:

```
export GREP=egrep
zgrep -H -e "(keyword1|keyword2)" some.file.*
```

Comment: Thanks! I just piped the `zgrep` output to `grep` for multiple keywords